# How can I implement the java hashmap by using PHP?

Tags: hashmap

I use PHP to process following input:
sam
99912222
tom
11122222
harry
12299933
sam
edward
harry
the 1st to 6th line are name and phone numbe. And the last three lines is the search query, if the name is not in the list(not have  phone number,print not found), otherwise output the data. My code as follow:

```
<?php
$_fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$list = array();
for($i = 0;$i<3;$i++){
    $name = strtolower(fgets($_fp));
    $phone = fgets($_fp);
    $list["$name"] = $phone;
}
for($i = 0;$i<3;$i++){
    $name = fgets($_fp);
    if(array_key_exists($name,$list)){
        echo "$name".'='."$list[$name]"."\n";
    }else{
        echo 'Not found'."\n";
    }
?>
```

Excepted output should be sam = 99912222 Not found harry = 12299933
The output is sam = 99912222 Not found Not found. why these function doesn't work?
This is a problem from hackerrank.
I know if I use hashmap in java is easy to solve. But how can I solve this problem in PHP?
Many thanks

Comment: Maybe there is a spurious space somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, trim off whitespace by using trim(fgets($_fp)) everywhere instead of just fgets($_fp) -- that fixes things on my end at least.

Second, the code you pasted is missing the closing curly bracket on your second for loop.

Third, have fun with 30 Days of Code :-) (once you get the above straightened out you also need to have your code read in the number of entries at the beginning, and "Read the queries until end-of-file" at the end).